# including a .lib file compiled in vs2010 in a project that is using vs2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

Is there any way I can have the main functions for a library built in vs 2010 be accessible from a vs2005 project? The problem that I face is that I have a project in vs 2005 that needs to use the clang frontend library to parse c code. The clang library requires vs 2010 to compile.

Any light you could shed on my problem is appreciated.

Thanks,
Saketh

EDIT:

I receive the following linker errors on compilation

`1>hello.lib(hello.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(_int64)" (_imp_?width@ios_base@std@@QAE_J_J@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::operator<< >(class std::basic_ostream > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
1>hello.lib(hello.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf >::sputn(char const *,_int64)" (_imp_?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE_JPBD_J@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::operator<< >(class std::basic_ostream > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
1>hello.lib(hello.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (_imp?width@ios_base@std@@QBE_JXZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::operator<< >(class std::basic_ostream > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z)
1>C:\Users\sakethk\Perforce\sakethk_SAKETHK_7702\source\qcom\qct\modem\uim\tools\sakethk\hello05\Debug\hello05.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals`

Comment: Did you try to link against the .lib generated with vs2010 in your vs2005 project?

Comment: yes. I got a linker error for every function in the lib file

Comment: Try adding the library in Additional Dependencies. It can be found in - "Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input-> Additional Dependencies". The path to the library should be specified in "Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories".

Comment: which error did you get?

Comment: @Mahesh, I tried that. I got the linker errors that I added when doing so

Comment: Can you show us the "_declspec" lines you used to export in the header file of your .lib? It could be a name mangling/calling convention problem.

Comment: @Étienne: Headers for static libraries don't use `__declspec()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Within a single module, you cannot mix objects compiled against different major versions of the CRT.  This generally procludes mixing of objects compiled using different major versions of the compiler.

The correct thing to do would be to encapsulate your usage of Visual C++ 2010 within a DLL, and load that DLL from your executable compiled with Visual C++ 2005.  Alternatively, upgrade your sources to use Visual C++ 2010.  Visual C++ 2005 is ancient.

Comment: so, Instead of building a static library, I would build a dll?

Comment: also, would I need both the vs2010 runtime and the vs2005 runtime to be available to run this code?

Comment: upgrading the project is not an option as my company has too many dependencies on this project to refactor it that drastically

Comment: Yes, to both questions.  (Statically linking with either or both CRTs would be another option, instead of relying on the CRT DLLs, but in general the recommendation is to use the CRT DLLs.)

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Would I just compile my current project as a dll? or should I do something else?

Comment: I cannot answer that question, as I have no idea what is in your project.  The general guidelines apply:  use a flat C API for the DLL interface boundary and avoid sharing CRT resources across the boundary (do not try to use a `FILE*` from one CRT with another CRT, do not try to free memory with one CRT that was allocated with another CRT, etc.)

Comment: @sakekasi why need to refactor? As someone who's just upgraded a company's VS2002 project to 2010, the job isn't particularly difficult (though its not totally cost-free). At least analyse the effort it would require to do this - it'll only make maintenance easier, especially when you have to move to VS2013+

Answer (score 0):

Your library functions should be at the lowest level here i mean that you should use C-style parameters to functions and use `extern "C"` to avoind compilers mangling. Here you will find good article on how to create a great library compatible with every compiler. http://chadaustin.me/cppinterface.html